# Upload of huge file using a web application

Tags: java, file-upload, file-io, nio, bulk

The environment for the given objective is not currenly available, hence, I'm not able to try out things and have to rely on the analysis only !

My objective can be broken into the following distinct steps :

1. Uploading huge files(upto **100GB**) using a dumb 'Upload File' page - there is no escape from this as the users want a (dumb)front-end and are not willing to ftp the file etc.
2. The web application which provides the above front end will be hosted on a low-end machine - 2GB RAM and 40GB HDD and this web application WILL NOT STORE any part of the huge file on the local machine but must 'quickly' write it to a high-end remote Linux machine

For each step, I'm highlighting my approach,concerns and queries :

- I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463655/huge-file-upload) thread which confused me as I was planning to create a dumb web application using Spring MVC with an upload page - do I need to go into the HTML5 etc. or a simple web application will suffice?
- Given the 2GB RAM, the web application will get less than 1GB of it. I'm afraid that an 'OutOfMemoryError' is probable if the code is not written strictly - I have to ensure that from the stream, a small chunk, say 10MB must be read at a time and written to the remote Linux machine's file.
  Assuming that I am in the Controller Servlet's doPost(...), I did some reading about how to proceed  and got confused :

  ```
        /**
           * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
           *      response)
           */
          protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                  HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              InputStream fis = request.getInputStream();
              int i = 0;

              /* Approach - 1 : Plain old byte-by-byte method */
              Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.90.20", 22);
              OutputStream remoteOpStream = socket.getOutputStream();

              while ((i = fis.read()) != -1) {
                  remoteOpStream.write(i);
              }

              /* clean-up */

              /* Approach - 2 : NIO */
              ByteBuffer byteBuff = ByteBuffer.allocate(10000);/* read 10MB of data */

              ReadableByteChannel rdbyc = Channels.newChannel(request
                      .getInputStream());

              File remoteFile = new File("192.168.90.20/Remote_Linux_Folder");/*
                                                                               * Dunno
                                                                               * how
                                                                               * to
                                                                               * create
                                                                               * a
                                                                               * File
                                                                               * on a
                                                                               * remote
                                                                               * Linux
                                                                               * machine
                                                                               */
              FileOutputStream remoteFos = new FileOutputStream(remoteFile);
              FileChannel writableChannel = remoteFos.getChannel();

              while (true/* dunno how to loop till all the data is read! */) {
                  rdbyc.read(byteBuff);
                  writableChannel.write(byteBuff);
              }

              /* clean-up */

          }
  ```

**I need some way wherein the data storage on the local machine is minimal - the code simply reads n bytes from the input stream and writes the same to a remote machine**

*I believe NIO is the way to go* but I'm not able to establish as to how I must proceed - please guide about the same.

Comment: Neither the Sevlet API or the standard java.io.File IO provide non-blocking APIs.  On most O/S platforms File IO is blocking but can be used with non-blocking Channels but the actual IO when you perform it is blocking (it is just too fast to usually notice the difference, due to O/S buffer cache, etc...).  If you really need a non-blocking File IO design look at AIO (Async I/O model) not NIO.  But if your destination for the data is across the network using a Socket then NIO is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a FixedSizeQueue and popAll() the data out of the QueueStream to another computer. Probably have it double buffered, just to provide the cushioning for network/bandwidth problems.

Comment: Hi Prototype Stark,
Sorry but I didn't get what you are hinting - please elaborate !