# DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA is not fired when the big file is uploaded where as fired when the small size file is uploaded

Tags: java, flash

The below is my code. This code is working fine when the file size is small. But not working when the size is large. I'm Sure server side content is written to the response. I can confirm upload is completed beacsue I can see the data in my Db table.
**max-post-size="2147483648** and **file upload size is 11.1MB**

```
private var fileReference:FileReferenceProgress = null;
private function onImportClick():void
{
    initReference();
}

private function initReference():void
{
    fileReference = new FileReferenceProgress();
    fileReference.addEventListener(DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA, onFileUpload);
}

private function onFileUpload(e:DataEvent):void
{
    if (e.data == "Success")
    {
        AlertDialog.show("Success", "Success", Alert.OK);
        executeLookup(_currentFilter);
    }
    else
        AlertDialog.show(e.data, "Error", Alert.OK);

    resetUpload();
}
```

Can Anyone please give me a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a wild guess, are you sure that "big" size does not exceed the web server max upload size? You can also try to figure out the limit after which the erroneous result occurs, that could give you some hints.

Comment: @Organis, max-post-size="2147483648 this is the size. But my upload file size is 11.1 MB only. It is processed in the server because i'm able to see it in my db table.
Any other hint Please?

Comment: In servlet response object I have added "Success" text also. But all back is not being called

Comment: What about PROGRESS event? I don't really like the idea, but if PROGRESS returns 100/100, then upload is probably complete? https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/ProgressEvent.html#PROGRESS This might help too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463655/huge-file-upload